# AdoNetAppender in log4net not logging or throwing exception

Tags: log4net, adonetappender

I have defined a logger in my log4net.config file that is supposed to use the AdoNetAppender to log to an instance of SQL Server 2005. The logger is being called in my code, but no messages are being logged and no exceptions are being thrown.

Here is the part of my config file defining the logger and the appender:

```xml
<logger name="Log4NetSummarySqlLogger">
  <level value="INFO"/>
  <appender-ref ref="SummarySqlAppender"/>
</logger>

<appender name="SummarySqlAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
<bufferSize value="100" />
<!--<connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />-->
<connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
<connectionString value="data source=[removed];initial catalog=[removed];integrated security=false;persist security info=True;User ID=[removed];Password=[removed]" />
<commandText value="INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@log_date" />
  <dbType value="DateTime" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
</parameter>
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@thread" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="255" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@log_level" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="50" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%level" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@logger" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="255" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@message" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="4000" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%message" />
  </layout>
</parameter>
<parameter>
  <parameterName value="@exception" />
  <dbType value="String" />
  <size value="2000" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
</parameter>
```

I also enabled log4net's internal debugging, and it wasn't of much help either:

```
log4net: log4net assembly [log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821]. Loaded from [<executable directory>\log4net.dll]. (.NET Runtime [4.0.30319.237] on Microsoft Windows NT 5.1.2600 Service Pack 3)
log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: defaultRepositoryType [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Creating repository for assembly [WindowsService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]
log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Assembly [WindowsService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] Loaded From [<executable directory>\WindowsService.exe]
log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Assembly [WindowsService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] does not have a RepositoryAttribute specified.
log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Assembly [WindowsService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] using repository [log4net-default-repository] and repository type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: DefaultRepositorySelector: Creating repository [log4net-default-repository] using type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: XmlConfigurator: configuring repository [log4net-default-repository] using file [<executable directory>\log4net.config]
log4net: XmlConfigurator: configuring repository [log4net-default-repository] using stream
log4net: XmlConfigurator: loading XML configuration
log4net: XmlConfigurator: Configuring Repository [log4net-default-repository]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Configuration update mode [Merge].
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Logger [root] Level string is [INFO].
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Logger [root] level set to [name="INFO",value=40000].
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Loading Appender [FileAppender] type: [log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [File] to String value [<log directory>/info.log]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [AppendToFile] to Boolean value [True]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [RollingStyle] to RollingMode value [Size]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [MaxSizeRollBackups] to Int32 value [10]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [MaximumFileSize] to String value [100KB]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [StaticLogFileName] to Boolean value [True]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [{%level}%date{MM/dd HH:mm:ss} - %message%newline]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [literal] Option [{] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [level] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [literal] Option [}] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [date] Option [MM/dd HH:mm:ss] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [literal] Option [ - ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.PatternLayout]
log4net: RollingFileAppender: Searched for existing files in [<log directory>]
log4net: RollingFileAppender: curSizeRollBackups starts at [0]
log4net: FileAppender: Opening file for writing [<log directory>\info.log] append [True]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Created Appender [FileAppender]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Adding appender named [FileAppender] to logger [root].
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Retrieving an instance of log4net.Repository.Logger for logger [Log4NetSummarySqlLogger].
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting [Log4NetSummarySqlLogger] additivity to [True].
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Logger [Log4NetSummarySqlLogger] Level string is [INFO].
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Logger [Log4NetSummarySqlLogger] level set to [name="INFO",value=40000].
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Loading Appender [SummarySqlAppender] type: [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [BufferSize] to Int32 value [100]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [ConnectionType] to String value [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [ConnectionString] to String value [data source=<server>;initial catalog=<database>;integrated security=false;persist security info=True;User ID=<user>;Password=<password>]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [CommandText] to String value [INSERT INTO Log ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@log_date]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [DateTime]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@thread]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [255]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%thread]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [thread] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@log_level]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [50]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%level]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [level] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@logger]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [255]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%logger]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [logger] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@message]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [4000]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%message]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@exception]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [2000]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
'QTAgent32.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'QTAgent32.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'QTAgent32.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.Wrapper.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Created Appender [SummarySqlAppender]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Adding appender named [SummarySqlAppender] to logger [Log4NetSummarySqlLogger].
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Retrieving an instance of log4net.Repository.Logger for logger [Log4NetEventLogger].
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting [Log4NetEventLogger] additivity to [True].
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Logger [Log4NetEventLogger] Level string is [INFO].
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Logger [Log4NetEventLogger] level set to [name="INFO",value=40000].
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Loading Appender [EventLogAppender] type: [log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [LogName] to String value [Application]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [ApplicationName] to String value [ConcurFilesService]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [{%level}%date{MM/dd HH:mm:ss} - %message%newline]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [literal] Option [{] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [level] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [literal] Option [}] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [date] Option [MM/dd HH:mm:ss] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [literal] Option [ - ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: PatternParser: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.PatternLayout]
log4net: EventLogAppender: Source [ConcurFilesService] is registered to log []
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Created Appender [EventLogAppender]
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Adding appender named [EventLogAppender] to logger [Log4NetEventLogger].
log4net: XmlHierarchyConfigurator: Hierarchy Threshold []
```

FWIW, I have also defined a FileAppender elsewhere and it works fine.

Answer (score 9):

Try to set the buffer size to 1. It is possible that your application quits before the buffer is flushed and thus you do not see any log messages.

```
bufferSize value="1"
```

Another possible problem could be the name of the logger. Do you really have a logger with this name? Try to configure the root logger instead

```
<root>
   <level value="INFO"/>
   <appender-ref ref="SummarySqlAppender"/>
</root>
```

Comment: Thanks Stefan. I tried doing as you suggested, and there still aren't any records that have been added to the database. I've tested the parameters in the connection string and they work. I've even had a coworker look at it and could find nothing wrong with the connection string. Besides building log4net from source and attaching a debugger, do you have any other suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: buffer size is 100 in the default/example configs. just changed it to '1' ... bammm !

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like log4net is being initialized okay, but something's amiss with this particular appender or logger.  Try adding a file appender to the Log4NetSummarySqlLogger and make sure the logger is actually being used.

The ADONetAppender can also fail if the SQL generated is invalid.  The failure won't cause an exception, but will issue an ERROR log entry to be written to STDERR.  If this is a windows GUI or service app, I highly recommend you test your config using a console application so any appender errors are easier to spot; these ERROR logs look like this:

```
log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] Exception while writing to database
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Da
te', table 'Test1.dbo.Log'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolea
n breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception
, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObj
ect stateObj)...
```

I read that you've tested the connection string; have you also tested the sql generated by the appender?  Verified that the database field sizes and types match the parameters in your config?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this and it was because the configuration was not initialized. So this is possibly different than that OPs issue. However in your app start you cannot forget this line:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```

log4net will just happily continue and not issue any warnings etc. I ended up downloading the source and rebuilding log4net so I could debug. For reference my Global.asax looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]
```